# VS 2019 solution build error due of The expression of an export assignment must be an identifier or qualified name in an ambient context

Tags: angular, typescript

When build solution in Visual Studio 2019, Typescript version 3.8.3, I got

```
The expression of an export assignment must be an identifier or qualified name in an ambient context.
```

in `index.d.ts` file at line 8: `export default "ui.router";`

```
// Type definitions for Angular JS (ui.router module) 1.1.5
// Project: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
// Definitions by: Michel Salib <https://github.com/michelsalib>, Ivan Matiishyn <https://github.com/matiishyn>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

import * as angular from 'angular';

export default "ui.router";

export type IState = angular.ui.IState;
```

How to solve it ?

Cannot publish web app due to this error